# C++ error C2679 '>>' binary no operator found

Tags: c++

I'm new here and I'm a student, so I'm sorry and a little patient with me. I am taking a course at Udemy on POO C ++ in which I have already taken a course on the basics in C and C ++. However, when developing the code in VS 2019, this error is occurring c2679 '>>' binary: no operator found that receives a right-hand operator of type 'function overloaded'. I have already researched and so far I have not been able to find a solution. Please, can you help me I will be grateful. Here is a bass or code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

class Carro {
    private:
        string marca;
        int ano;
    public:
        //Parametro para leitura da variavel MARCA
        void setMarca(string x) {
            marca = x;
        }
        //Imprimir a variavel MARCA
        string getMarca() {
            return marca;
        }

        //Parametro para leitura da variavel ANO
        void setAno(int y) {
            ano = y;
        }
        //Imprimir a variavel ANO
        int getAno() {
            return ano;
        }
};

int main()
{   //Lendo as variaveis ANO e MODELO
    Carro c1;
    cout << "Digite o nome da marca do primeiro carro: ";
    cin >> c1.setMarca;    <- Erro C2679
    cout << "Digite o ano do primeiro carro: ";
    cin >> c1.setAno;      <- Erro C2679

    //Imprimindo na tela as variaveis
    cout << "A marca do primeiro carro eh: " << c1.getMarca() << endl;
    cout << "O ano do primeiro carro eh: " << c1.getAno() << endl;

    //Pausa o programa
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post here -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the string insertion operator (`>>`) to get input into a function. This no overload of `>>` for doing that, and that's what the error is telling you.

I'd suggest doing your input into temporary variables, and then calling the setters:

```
Carro c1;
std::string marca;
int ano;
cout << "Digite o nome da marca do primeiro carro: ";
cin >> marca;
c1.setMarca(marca);
cout << "Digite o ano do primeiro carro: ";
cin >> ano;
c1.setAno(ano);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it worked perfectly. In the next question I will already do it in English.

Comment: @RiderBR: Glad I could help. And [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) is there too if that's easier for you.